# Issues with deploying artifacts in Nexus repository

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, nexus

We are in the process of deploying artifacts into the nexus repository and facing issues.

Issue

we are facing issues with Nexus integration. We have included `<distributionManagement>` tag in the  project pom.xml  and it contains the snapshot repository and Repository details. Below is the tag  that we have included.

```xml
<groupId>Test</groupId>
<artifactId>testSP</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<distributionManagement>
<snapshotRepository>
 <id>deployment</id>
 <name>Internal Releases</name>
 <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</snapshotRepository>
<repository>
 <id>deployment</id>
 <name>Internal Releases</name>
 <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository> 
</distributionManagement>
<repositories>
<repository>
   <!-- DO NOT set id to "local" because it is reserved by Maven -->
   <id>lib</id>
   <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

When we try to build the Jenkins job, we are getting a build failure error. With the below message.

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-    plugin:2.7:
deploy (default-deploy) on project testSP: Failed to deploy artifacts: Cou
ld not find artifact Test:testSP:war:2.0 in deployment (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

The build works fine if the distribution management tag is removed. For some reasons the artifacts are not uploaded in nexus.

Analysis Done

Below are the analysis that we have done.

- Added nexus server as a non proxy host in settings.xml
- Checked the user credentials for accessing the nexus server & also checked the access permission
- The url to the server was also  correct
- We are trying to deploy it in the release repository of nexus and have also checked/updated the version in pom.xml

Any help in fixing the above issue is much appreciated.

Comment: The given repository configuration where you have `<url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>` does not make sense if you are using a repository manager. Deploy the artifact you need into nexus..

Comment: I updated the url to nexus repository url. But still Im facing the same issue. Getting the above exception. Please Advice

Comment: Try giving your snapshotRepo and repo each a unique name OR unique ID. Update the server login details to reflect this if you change id field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But can u please elaborate on this. Thanks. Also i tried updating the artifact in snapshot repo by updating version to 1.0-SNAPSHOT. But it is looking for some war file with timestamp. But the war file with timestamp is not deployed anywhere. I will update the error below.

Comment: [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ testSP --Downloading:http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/Test/testSP/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml Uploading:http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/Test/testSP/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testSP-1.0-20160202.111830-1.war
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/Test/testSP/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testSP-1.0-20160202.111830-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.546 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-02T03:18:33-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy (default-deploy) on project testSP: Failed to deploy artifacts:Could not find artifact Test:testSP:war:1.0-20160202.111830-1 in nexus (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? Is Nexus running as a service or foreground, if service: with what user? Please check, whether the windows user has necessary permissions to write into the storage folder.

Comment: Hi im using windows server2012 and nexus is running as a service. Its using the local system account. i just checked, the account that is running the service is an administrative account in the server . So i guess it has the necessary permission